# Matching values from two different tables efficiently

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables

```
 class CreateMasterUrls < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   \create_table :master_urls do |t|
  t.string :url
  t.string :host

  t.timestamps
 end
 add_index :master_urls, [:url], :name => :idx_url
 add_index :master_urls, [:host], :name => :idx_host
 end
end
```

and

```
 class CreateUrlLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  create_table :url_lists do |t|
  t.string :url
  t.integer :project_id

  t.timestamps
 end
 end
end
```

I want to check whether URL present in url_lists table is present in master_urls, if not than add it in master_urls table. Any clue how to do that?

One way would be to do regex match. But it is not efficient and also not solving problem.

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: mysql community edition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try something along these (SQL) lines . . .

```
insert into master_urls (url)
select ul.url 
from url_list ul
where ul.url not in (select url from master_urls);
```

That's not the most efficient way to do it, but it's easy to understand.

But this isn't your *real* problem.

If there's a requirement that all the urls from url_list must always be in master_urls, then you need to use the dbms to make sure that happens. Depending on your application, you might need foreign key constraints, triggers, or significant changes in application code.